# Window stuck on 'Force UEFI installation?' window

Tags: dual-boot, bug-reporting

I'm using a Macbook Pro w/ Intel i5 processor and have attempted to install ubuntu 15.10, 64-bit as dual boot along with OSX. I booted Ubuntu using a USB and went through the installation process, selected a partition and swap space and installed Ubuntu. However, at the point where the 'where are you?' screen pops up, I get a Force UEFI installation window that invariably gets stuck, the two options are 'Go Back' and 'Continue'. After some browsing, I realised that [this is a recognised bug](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/foundations-bugs/2015-April/232879.html), but none of the sites seem to give a way to deal with this bug or the steps I should take to navigate my way out of this.

A little help is needed, thanks.

(**On a similar note**: if such an error presents itself, is there a faster way of restarting installation than logging out and using the default 'ubuntu' username as the 'xkill' command line in the terminal is not available pre-install . )

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that the problem exists with the option presented in the first installation screen 'Download Updates while Installing'.

Nevertheless, given that this bug was reported in May 2015 - it should have been dealt with by now.

**UPDATE**: Based on a comment by ‘Nur’, he/she has noted that it might not only suffice to have the Download Updates option unchecked - you must also disconnect yourself from the internet.

Comment: Sadly, as of late February 2016, this issue is still alive and well. Had me screaming at random objects until I saw your answer. Thanks.

Comment: The bug is still alive in the Xenial Xerus 16.04 build!

Comment: Not selecting this option did not help. Still stuck there.

Comment: Csn confirm the bug is still occuring on Kylin...

Comment: Bug still happens Nov 2016, in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Comment: And it still happens even on Mar 8 2017, Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. Seems Canonical doesn't care.

Comment: Still happens. What a joke. 17.04

Comment: Elementary OS in the same boat

Comment: Wait so how do you people get past this window?

Comment: EDIT: Figured it out, it is not enough to simply uncheck "Download updates...", instead, internet must never be connected at all.

Comment: @Nur YES! I have pulled all my hair out and then I saw your comment. Thank you.

Comment: Still the case 16.04.3 LTS !

Answer (score 1):

User [Fabien #11](https://launchpad.net/~id-ubuntu) has a perfect workaround that was posted in [this launchpad link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1547286). I am just copying his solution here (of course all credit goes to Fabien). Here's the solution:

---

-create new partition table on the disk by selecting "something else",
-add FAT32 part on the SSD (NOT EFI),
-add other partitions (as usual), like boot, home etc,
-click next and a pop-up about the missing EFI appears ->click go back,
-select the first FAT32 partition mentioned above, change it to EFI,
-click next and installation will go smooth.

---

I will also recommend "uncheck"ing "updates during installation" and "third party softwares...".

Goodluck