# Trying to install Ubuntu mate 15.10

Tags: system-installation, mate, ubuntu-mate

Hi i'm trying to install buntu mate on my new pc.
I had a wierd bug where it got struk after partioning;

[Window stuck on 'Force UEFI installation?' window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693732/window-stuck-on-force-uefi-installation-window)

after i figured this out i had to restart the installaton, (i've read the only way to do that is turn off the power)

```
edit: 
i get a green splash screen before the screen goes black/gray 
(i also added spacing to th specs section)
edit3:
downloaded a new ubuntu mate file, but it didn't change a thing.
it seems to get into the os fine, but it just doesn't give me the graphical data
(i can see my mouse and move it, and when i move it over where the 
buttons from the mate startup menu should be the courser changes, but i cant see anything)
```

now when i try to install again the top 1/3 screen is black and the lowest 2/3 are gray, but it seems i'm in the os (in the try without installing area)

i've read that i have to use nomodeset, and that to do this i have to press either e or downarrow afte you choose try os without installing, but none of this seems to do anything

```
edit 2: 
i found out i had to push e while the "try ubuntu mate" option was highlighted
i did this and then wrote nomodeset noveau.modeset=0
but it still doesn't work
```

specs:

```
Intel Core i5-6600K 3.5Ghz

NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970

8 gigs of  ram
```

thanks for the help

```
edit 4:
```

a guy told me to go into the terminal with alt + crtl + f1, i did so, and logged in with ubuntu-mate with a blank password, then i did:

```
startx
```

this made the desktop show up, but it has twisted and wierd colors, should i install this? or redownload again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when inside the os you push:

```
alt + crtl + fx
```

where x is any number between 1 and 7

it'll ask for a username and keyword

the username is ubuntu-mate
there is no password

then you write

```
sudo startx
```

this will clear up some of the screen, but not all, to clear all you push

```
alt + crtl + fx
```

where x is a number between 1 and 7 (not including the number you used before)

you log in and use startx as before (the process needed to be repeated 3 times for me every time i start and every time i log in)

Then you install XD